# Unable to fetch result of Python Script in PHP

Tags: php, python

I am using Xampp and Ubuntu 16.04..

now for my project i need python and php integration to call python script from PHP. Actually describing my script... I am using pypi newspaper library to extract a news summary from a news web portal

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from newspaper import Article
url='http://www.abplive.in/india-news/countering-terrorism-an-important-shared-objective-by-india-united-states-manohar-parrikar-407134'
article=Article(url)
article.download()
article.parse()
article.nlp()
print article.summary
```

So just help me out with a code in php to call a python script

Answer (score 0):

One of the `passthru()` or `exec()` commands should do the trick. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php for more info. Something like:

```
<?php
    $full_path = `<full_path_to_python_script>`;
    passthru($full_path);
?>
```